# How to Split DistinguishedName?

Tags: powershell, distinguishedname

I have a list of folks and their DN from AD (I do not have direct access to that AD).  Their DNs are in format:

```
$DNList = 'CN=Bob Dylan,OU=Users,OU=Dept,OU=Agency,OU=NorthState,DC=myworld,DC=com',
          'CN=Ray Charles,OU=Contractors,OU=Dept,OU=Agency,OU=NorthState,DC=myworld,DC=com',
          'CN=Martin Sheen,OU=Users,OU=Dept,OU=Agency,OU=WaySouth,DC=myworld,DC=com'
```

I'd like to make `$DNList` return the following:

```
OU=Users,OU=Dept,OU=Agency,OU=NorthState,DC=myworld,DC=com
OU=Contractors,OU=Dept,OU=Agency,OU=NorthState,DC=myworld,DC=com
OU=Users,OU=Dept,OU=Agency,OU=WaySouth,DC=myworld,DC=com
```

Comment: There are already a lot of good answers here. I just want to point out that the "fields" in a DN can themselves contain a comma, and when they do it's escaped with a backslash so you can have `CN=Dylan\, Bob,OU=Users`. Just be careful that whichever method you choose handles this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I decided to turn my comment into an answer:

```powershell
$DNList | ForEach-Object {
    $_ -replace '^.+?(?<!\\),',''
}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/fZaioaU-JxWPAxns)

This will correctly handle escaped commas that are part of the first component.

We do a non-greedy match for one or more characters at the beginning of the string, then look for a comma that is not preceded by a backslash (so that the dot will match the backslash and comma combination and keep going).

Comment: Oh crap that's true isn't it.

Comment: My job uses `Last, First` display names in AD so I see this all the time :)

Comment: Tried to salvage my answer with this fact.

Comment: I did go with this answer and the resulting data looks good, at least on a random spot check.  It was odd, however... running against a list of 1600ish items, the first dozen or so, it seemed like the whole process timed out and/jammed up.  But waited about 20+ seconds and a quick flash with the correct results.  Odd as it looked, it worked clean and clear.  Thank you very, very much!

Comment: I think this may fail, when a value ends with an escaped backslash '\\' before the comma to the next OU will follow. E.g. OU=\\myOU\\,OU=mycompany\, inc.

Comment: @Carsten yes I think so, at some point in the years since I wrote this I had a regex that properly accounted for that, but I keep losing it and rewriting it when I need it  I think it used some kind of repetition on a group of backslash pairs or something, I was inspired by the method of using regex to tell if a number is prime by converting it to unary.

Answer (score 3):

You can remove the first element with a replacement like this:

```
$DNList -replace '^.*?,(..=.*)$', '$1'
```

`^.*?,` is the shortest match from the beginning of the string to a comma.
`(..=.*)$` matches the rest of the string (starting with two characters after the comma followed by a `=` character) and groups them, so that the match can be referenced in the replacement as `$1`.

Comment: Nice - I think the split/join might be more readable if you're less familiar with powershell (or regular expressions) but is the regex faster? (wouldn't matter for this example but thinking of where there more are items to work on than the 3 here)

Comment: @GrahamGold About factor 10 faster, according to a quick test I just ran on a larger sample (1300 elements). Also, simply splitting the DNs might cause problems when the first element contains a comma.

Comment: I had a feeling it might be :-) Kudos for testing that out

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Grahams answer but removed the hardcoded array values so it will just remove the CN portion without worrying how long the DN is.

```
$DNList | ForEach-Object{($_ -split "," | Select-Object -Skip 1) -join ","}
```

Ansgar most likely has a good reason but you can just use regex to remove every before the first comma

```
$DNList -replace "^.*?,"
```

**Update based on briantist**

To maintain a different answer but one that works this regex can still have issues but I doubt these characters will appear in a username

```
$DNList -replace "^.*?,(?=OU=)"
```

Regex uses a look ahead to be sure the , is followed by `OU=`

Similarly you could do this

```
($DNList | ForEach-Object{($_ -split "(,OU=)" | Select-Object -Skip 1) -join ""}) -replace "^,"
```

Comment: With powershell there's more than one way to achieve the same objective - the answers on this question are proof positive :-) Why I love (and sometimes hate) powershell!

Comment: @GrahamGold very true. It how I learn other approaches. Seeing what other people do.

Answer (score 1):

You have 7 items per user, comma separated and you want rid of the first one.

So, split each item in the array using commas as the delimiter, return matches 1-6 (0 being the first item that you want to skip), then join with commas again e.g.

```
$DNList = $DNList|foreach{($_ -split ',')[1..6] -join ','}
```

If you then enter `$DNList` it returns

```
OU=Users,OU=Dept,OU=Agency,OU=NorthState,DC=myworld,DC=com
OU=Contractors,OU=Dept,OU=Agency,OU=NorthState,DC=myworld,DC=com
OU=Users,OU=Dept,OU=Agency,OU=WaySouth,DC=myworld,DC=com
```

Comment: When I try that, I get a result that's not what the OP is looking for :-  OU=Users,CN=Bob Dylan,DC=com
OU=Contractors,CN=Ray Charles,DC=com
OU=Users,CN=Martin Sheen,DC=com

Comment: You're right. What I head in mind was meant for a different scenario. Please disregard this suggestion. @Matt's suggestion is a better way to handle variable lengths.

Answer (score 0):

Just for convenience, the following code does *exactly* what the question asked vs. the more general answers provided.

```
$DNList | ForEach-Object { (($_ -replace "^CN=","") -split "(CN=|OU=)" | Select-Object -Skip 1) -join "" }
```

To get all the unique values (which is what I needed):

```
($DNList | ForEach-Object { (($_ -replace "^CN=","") -split "(CN=|OU=)" | Select-Object -Skip 1) -join "" }) | Select-Object -Unique
```